# I am installing kubernetes on ubuntu 14.04 VM, I am unable to install

Tags: kubernetes

Hi I am trying to install kubernetes on a vm with ubuntu 14.04, using manual from http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/ 
I tried

```
KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
```

I am getting following error:

```
etcd start/pre-start, process 1557
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: getsockopt: connection refused
error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Following is the content of `/var/log/upstart/etcd.log`:

```
2016-10-24 13:28:54.269743 I | etcdmain: listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
2016-10-24 13:28:54.269852 I | etcdmain: listening for peers on http://localhost:7001
2016-10-24 13:28:54.269921 I | etcdmain: listening for client requests on http://127.0.0.1:4001
2016-10-24 13:28:54.269994 I | etcdmain: stopping listening for client requests on http://127.0.0.1:4001
2016-10-24 13:28:54.270017 I | etcdmain: stopping listening for peers on http://localhost:7001
2016-10-24 13:28:54.270052 I | etcdmain: stopping listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
```

I am using it behind corporate proxy, http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy has been set
I tried versions `KUBE_VERSION=1.2.0`, `FLANNEL_VERSION=0.5.0`, `ETCD_VERSION=2.2.0`
I even tried different version for KUBE 1.1.8, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.4 But ended up is same error.

Kindly Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out solution, Kindly refer this page https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19235#issuecomment-255987755